# QtCreator - Import folders into resources?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, qresource

Is it somehow possible to import a folder structure into a resources file?

I have folders such as:

```
- JS
  - Lots of JS files
- Images
  - Lots of images

etc.
```

I can only seem to import one file at a time, I have around 80 files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Hello? Do you still need help?

Comment: Time to give up helping?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything, but this python script should give you some idea for a quick'n dirty workaround:

#### main.py

```
import os

print('<RCC>')
print('<qresource prefix="/">')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for name in files:
        print('<file>%s</file>' % name)

print('</qresource>')
print('/RCC')
```

Then, you can invoke the script as follows:

```
python main.py myfolder
```

Diclaimer: the code does not check against len(sys.argv), etc, but it would be pretty simple to extend and hand-craft it further. It does not write into a dedicated file either, but you can redirect the output, and so on.